# IIS runs out of memory while processing LESS files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, less, iis-8

After deploying an MVC application to the production server, this is the error I'm seeing when run locally:

```
During translation of LESS-code, readed from the file '/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less', to CSS-code syntax error has occurred.  See more details:

Error type: Syntax Message: Out of stack space File: /Content/bootstrap/mixins/labels.less

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: BundleTransformer.Core.Translators.AssetTranslationException: During translation of LESS-code, readed from the file '/Content/bootstrap/bootstrap.less', to CSS-code syntax error has occurred.  See more details:

Error type: Syntax
Message: Out of stack space
File: /Content/bootstrap/mixins/labels.less

Source Error:     

Line 6:      <title></title> 
Line 7:      <meta name="description"> content="APPLICATION_NAME" /> 
Line 8:      @Styles.Render("~/bundles/css") 
Line 9:      @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") 
Line 10:     <link> rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/CSS/alertify.core.css">
```

This all works fine on other servers.

> NOTE: It may be worth mentioning that the server with the problem only
>   has 8GB of RAM and there is another web application and a SQL database
>   running on it. This is my top suspect but I would like other opinions
>   if possible.

I have tried adding

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

to the `App_Start.RegisterBundles` class but this made no difference.

Someone has suggested I convert all the LESS to CSS, but this is using standard Bootstrap so there are a lot of files to go through!

Comment: You can download standard Bootstrap css files if that is your only reason.

Comment: Actually I don't think the problem is RAM related. When monitoring it during page refreshes, there is loads of free space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by enabling 32 bit applications for the application pool.

No idea why; I didn't need to do this for my dev server, so it must be because of the specific config of the production server.

Hope it helps someone anyway!